# How to remove nested field of Json object using Gson

Tags: java, json, gson

My `JSON` response:

```
{
    "date": 1555044585641,
    "changed": true,
    "data": {
        "items": [
            {
               "id": 503,
                "activated": false,
                "view": {
                    "listItem": {
                        ...
                    },
                    "details": {
                        ...
                    }
                }       
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I am using below class to parse `JSON` using `Gson`:

```
public class Response {

    @SerializedName("date")
    public long date;

    @SerializedName("changed")
    public boolean changed;

    @SerializedName("data")
    public JsonObject data;
}
```

I save "data" part as a string using `data.toString()` since data is `JsonObject`. My question is:

**How can I exclude "details" part before saving?**

Saved string should look like:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
           "id": 503,
            "activated": false,
            "view": {
                "listItem": {
                    ...
                }
            }       
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to traverse `JSON` structure using `JsonElement`, `JsonArray`, `JsonObject`:

```
class Response {

    @SerializedName("date")
    public long date;

    @SerializedName("changed")
    public boolean changed;

    @SerializedName("data")
    public JsonObject data;

    public void removeDetails() {
        JsonElement items = data.get("items");
        if (!items.isJsonArray()) {
            return;
        }
        JsonArray array = items.getAsJsonArray();
        array.forEach(item -> {
            if (item.isJsonObject()) {
                JsonObject node = item.getAsJsonObject();
                JsonElement view = node.get("view");
                if (view.isJsonObject()) {
                    view.getAsJsonObject().remove("details");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

After deserialisation invoke `removeDetails()` and you can save only required data.